# How to use fullCalendar's validRange feature?

Tags: fullcalendar

I've tried and just can't seem to get it to work.

Fwiw, everything else in fullCalendar I've succeeded with.

I'm trying to get valid Range to give me a range of the current month and the next month.  Their docs mention:

```
validRange: function(nowDate) {
  return {
    start: nowDate,
    end: nowDate.clone().add(2, 'months')
  };
},
```

I've also tried adding javascript code before the `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {` line, to no avail.

Can you help?

Edit:  I am not using jQuery

Comment: Hi, Please try to mention version of the api which you are working with. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate  in more detail what you want to achieve. Also, is there any error coming or showing in console ?

Comment: "can't get it to work" isn't enough of a description for us to help you. Exactly what were you hoping to achieve? And exactly what is happening instead? What version of fullCalendar are you using? Can you show the rest of your calendar code please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example if you need more guidance.